# Read text file from phone in android

Tags: java, android, io, text-files

I am trying to access a text file in android, but it is giving an error `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` where as the text file is present in the phone.

```
        if (txt_file.endsWith(".txt")) {
              try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "path " + txt_file);
                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(txt_file);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                         bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
                    byte[] dataToSave = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                    }
          }
```

I have logged the `txt_file` before the `InputStream` and it is returning the correct path of the text file.

Comment: Try to use **Scanner** instead of  InputStream to read file

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more because there is error in `is.read(b)` as there is no read method using Scanner.

Comment: `Log.e("TAG", "path " + txt_file);` Please tell us the used path.

Comment: You should add: `if ( !new File(txt_file).exists() return;`

Comment: You should also add: `if ( !new File(txt_file).canRead() return;`

Comment: this is the used path  `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AdeviceId.txt`

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
 fun readFile(file: File?): String {
        var fileContent: String = ""
        try {
            val scan = Scanner(file)

            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                fileContent = scan.nextLine()
            }
            scan.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            fileContent = ""
        }
        return fileContent
    }
```